# Varying arguments for if () statement

Tags: c, if-statement, conditional-statements, varying

I have a problem as stated below:
i have an array(say) a[]={10,24,56,33,22,11,21}
i have something like this

```
for(i=0;i<100;i++){
    if(a[i]==10)
        // do something
}
```

next when i=1

```
if(a[i]==10 && a[i+1]==24)
```

so on so at each iteration the arguments / conditions within if should be varying
now this will be a very big sequence i cant explicitly write
`if(a[i]==10 && a[i+1]==24 && a[i+2]==56 ......  a[i+100]=2322)`

how can i achieve this varying conditions?

Comment: Your problem statement isn't clear. I suspect you have to use a loop in place of your `if` statement with many conditions.

Comment: Can we suppose the input shown isn't the real input or all of this would be out of the array bounds?

Comment: what's the objective of the program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to have a cumulative "boolean" variable that checks a[i] at the i-th iteration and update that variable:

```
int a[] = {...};   /* array with some values to verify */
int v[] = {...};   /* these are the actual desired values in a[] */

/* the verifying loop */
int i;
int cond = 1;
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    cond = cond && (a[i] == v[i]);
    if (cond)
    {
       /* do something */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a loop within a loop:

```
for (i = 0; i != 100; ++i)
{
    int condition = 1;
    for (j = 0; i + j != 100 && condition; ++j)
    {
        condition = condition && (a[i + j] == /* your number */ );
    }
    if (condition) { /* ... */ }
}
```

Comment: In the `for (j = 0; i + j != 100; ++j)` loop you can add optimization `if (!condition) break;`. Better practice is to use `i < 100` rather than `i != 100`.

Comment: And the condition must be `1` at the beginning. If it's `0` then it never will change to `1`,

Comment: This is not C++, you cannot declare the variable `condition` inside a `for` loop.

Comment: @ssjeitan: It might not be C++, but it’s still block-scoped.  Variables can be defined at the beginning of any block in C, not just a function-scope block.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should introduce a boolean value.

```
bool valid = true;

for(i=0;i<100;i++){
    if(a[i]==10 && valid)
        // do something
    else
    {
        valid = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

For every iteration, you need to change the value to which you are comparing `a[i]`

Comment: `boolean` is not a C type. use `bool` or `_Bool`.

Comment: What's the point of `valid`, if you have to manually enter each value inside the loop?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can use function pointers or blocks. 
 You can find a good example here [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#featuredarticles/BuildingWithBlocks/_index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your examples, I think that the variations you are talking about is only in the length of array 'a' whose presence you want to check in some array x. If indeed it is so, memcmp can be of use to you.

Let me modify your example a bit to clarify what I am saying.

int a[7]={10,24,56,33,22,11,21} is the required values you want to check in some array 'x', with different lengths of 'a' each time, with 'x' declared as

```
int x[1000];
```

In that case, you could use memcmp as follow :-

```
for ( len = 1 ; len <= 7 ; ++len )
{ for ( i = 0 ; i <= 1000-len ; ++i )
  { if ( ! memcmp( a, x+i, len * sizeof(int) ) )
    { // do something
    }
  }
}
```